# Wallet did not finish creating node and cannot connect to daemon anymore

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon

Errors:
`Cannot read property 'daemonLogPath' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'walletLogPath' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'walletCreationHeight' of null`

full readout in Bash:
`app startd
qml: check next false
qml: Checking seed
qml: check next false
qml: check next false
qml: log level changed:  0
qml: transfer page loaded
qml: PrivacyLevel changed:0
qml: mixin count: 4
qml: log level changed:  1
qml: qrScannerEnabled disabled
qml: setting demo token
qml: initializing..
setLanguage   "en"
qml: transfer page loaded
qml: PrivacyLevel changed:0
qml: mixin count: 4
qml: opening wallet at:  /Users/gingerbread_boy/Monero/wallets/monero/monero , testnet:  false
qrc:///pages/Settings.qml:503: TypeError: Cannot read property 'walletCreationHeight' of undefined
qrc:///pages/Settings.qml:520: TypeError: Cannot read property 'walletCreationHeight' of undefined
Checking for updates
Wallet *WalletManager::openWallet(const QString &, const QString &, bool): opening wallet at /Users/gingerbread_boy/Monero/wallets/monero/monero, testnet = 0 
2018-03-04 01:01:11.023   0x70000c4c4000    ERROR   net.http    contrib/epee/include/storages/portable_storage.h:161    portable_storage: wrong binary format - signature mismatch
2018-03-04 01:01:11.023   0x70000c4c4000    ERROR   wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:2128 !r. THROW EXCEPTION: error::invalid_password
2018-03-04 01:01:11.023   0x70000c4c4000    WARN    net.http    src/wallet/wallet_errors.h:707  /Users/buildbot/slave/monero-core-osx-10_11/build/monero/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:2128:N5tools5error16invalid_passwordE: invalid password
2018-03-04 01:01:11.024   0x70000c4c4000    ERROR   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:504   Error opening wallet: invalid password
Wallet *WalletManager::openWallet(const QString &, const QString &, bool): opened wallet: 41d7FXjswpK1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112KhNi4, status: 2
AddressBook
getAll
qml: languages availible:  17
qml: check next false
qml: >>> wallet opened: Wallet(0x7fa84c55fe70)
qml: Error opening wallet with empty password:  invalid password
qml: closing wallet async : 41d7FXjswpK1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112KhNi4
qrc:///pages/Settings.qml:520: TypeError: Cannot read property 'walletCreationHeight' of undefined
qrc:///pages/Settings.qml:503: TypeError: Cannot read property 'walletCreationHeight' of undefined
~Wallet: Closing wallet
2018-03-04 01:01:11.081   0x70000c4c4000    ERROR   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:553   Status_Critical - not storing wallet
m_walletImpl deleted
qml: >>> wallet closed: 41d7FXjswpK1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112KhNi4
2018-03-04 01:01:12.690   0x70000c547000    WARN    net.dns src/common/dns_utils.cpp:487    WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received
Checking for updates - done
qml: initializing..
setLanguage   "en"
qml: transfer page loaded
qml: PrivacyLevel changed:0
qml: mixin count: 4
qml: opening wallet at:  /Users/gingerbread_boy/Monero/wallets/monero/monero , testnet:  false
Wallet *WalletManager::openWallet(const QString &, const QString &, bool): opening wallet at /Users/gingerbread_boy/Monero/wallets/monero/monero, testnet = 0 
2018-03-04 01:01:29.464   0x70000c4c4000    WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:2505 Loaded wallet keys file, with public address: my_address
Wallet *WalletManager::openWallet(const QString &, const QString &, bool): opened wallet: my_address, status: 0
AddressBook
getAll
qml: >>> wallet opened: Wallet(0x7fa850437770)
qml: initializing with daemon address:  localhost:18081
qml: Recovering from seed:  false
qml: restore Height 0
"initAsync: localhost:18081"
init non async
init async finished - starting refresh
Checking connection status
2018-03-04 01:01:30.183   0x70000c4c4000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
NEW STATUS  Wallet::ConnectionStatus(ConnectionStatus_Disconnected)
qml: Wallet connection status changed 0
sending external cmd:  ("status")
2018-03-04 01:01:30.184   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
"Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081\n"
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
qml: >>> wallet updated
qml: Displaying processing splash
" [] "
"starting monerod /Users/gingerbread_boy/Downloads/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/MacOS/monerod"
With command line arguments  ("--detach", "--check-updates", "disabled")
2018-03-04 01:01:36.156   0x7fffa6f29340    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:279 Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.1.0-release)
Forking to background...
sending external cmd:  ("status")
"Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081\n"
daemon not running. checking again in 2 seconds.
sending external cmd:  ("status")
"Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081\n"
daemon not running. checking again in 2 seconds.
sending external cmd:  ("status")
"Height: 1344551/1344551 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 99.74 MH/s, v5, update needed, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 29s\n"
daemon is started. Waiting 5 seconds to let daemon catch up
qml: daemon started
qml: Hiding processing splash
Checking connection status
2018-03-04 01:02:14.743   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:02:14.744   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:02:24.749   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:02:24.757   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:02:34.752   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:02:34.757   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:02:44.756   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:02:44.768   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:02:54.757   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:02:54.764   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:03:04.760   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:03:04.768   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:03:14.761   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:03:14.767   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:03:24.764   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:03:24.765   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:03:34.768   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:03:34.775   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:03:44.771   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:03:44.773   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:03:54.772   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:03:54.773   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:04:04.773   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:04:04.774   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:04:24.774   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:04:24.775   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:04:34.775   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:04:34.776   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:04:44.776   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:04:44.777   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:04:54.778   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:04:54.779   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:05:04.781   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:05:04.782   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:05:14.783   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:05:14.798   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:05:24.785   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:05:24.786   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:05:34.786   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:05:34.789   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:05:44.788   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:05:44.791   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
2018-03-04 01:05:54.792   0x70000c1b2000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
refreshed
qml: >>> wallet refreshed
Checking connection status
qml: >>> wallet updated
2018-03-04 01:05:54.804   0x70000c547000    WARN    net contrib/epee/include/net/net_helper.h:177   Some problems at connect, message: Connection refused
sending external cmd:  ("status")
"Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081\n"
DaemonManager: exit()
~Wallet: Closing wallet
m_walletImpl deleted
qrc:///pages/Settings.qml:576: TypeError: Cannot read property 'daemonLogPath' of null
qrc:///pages/Settings.qml:572: TypeError: Cannot read property 'walletLogPath' of null
qrc:///pages/Settings.qml:520: TypeError: Cannot read property 'walletCreationHeight' of null
qrc:///pages/Settings.qml:503: TypeError: Cannot read property 'walletCreationHeight' of null`

Comment: Also, could anyone point me to a decent monero cli tutorial not on windows?

Comment: Use that ^ guide to resolve your issue. Re: CLI tutorial, see: https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/monero-wallet-cli.html or https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-create-a-command-line-monero-wallet